# Redirect by gesturedetector to the specific profile FLUTTER

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am making the searchPage and I don't know how I can manage for the user, when they find the name that exist to be able to touch it and be redirected to that specific page of the user profile they found.
Here is my code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flappy_search_bar/flappy_search_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'UserProfiles.dart';
import 'viewProfiles.dart';

class Searchbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SearchBarState createState() => SearchBarState();
}

class SearchBarState extends State<Searchbar> {
  TextEditingController textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final database = Firestore.instance;
  String searchString;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Container(
            child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, right: 280),
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                iconSize: 30.0,
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              ),
            ),
            TopText(),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: 40.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: TextField(
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            searchString = val.toLowerCase();
                          });
                        },
                        controller: textEditingController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                                onPressed: () => textEditingController.clear()),
                            hintText: " Search company name here ",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                                color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: (searchString == null || searchString.trim() == '')
                        ? Firestore.instance.collection('Users').snapshots()
                        : Firestore.instance
                            .collection('Users')
                            .where('name', isEqualTo: searchString)
                            .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('We got an error ${snapshot.error}');
                      }
                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                          return SizedBox(
                            child: Center(
                              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                            ),
                          );
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                          return Text('Oops no data present');

                        case ConnectionState.done:
                          return Text('We are done');

                        default:
                          return new ListView(
                              children: snapshot.data.documents
                                  .map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                            return new ListTile(
                              title: Text(document.data['name']),
                            );
                          }).toList());
                      }
                    },
                  )),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        )));
  }
}

class TopText extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Hey there,\n we can help you find ",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
                      fontSize: 24),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

And here is something that I used before

```
 return GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
//                                  Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>ViewUserPage()));
                                  Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      new MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (_) => StoryProfiles(
                                              UserProfiles(
                                                  '${snapshot.data.documents[index].data['id']}',
                                                  snaps.data['name'],
                                                  snaps.data['avatarUrl'],
                                                  snaps.data['address'],
                                                  snapshot.data.documents[index]
                                                      .data['categoryName']))));
                                },
```

but I don't know how I can add it here..